# How to display json data in datepicker calendar using Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, datepicker

I am new to Angularjs and quite not sure where to start from,i need to display data(coming from a json) under each date in datepicker.

I have my datepicker calendar ready.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="720kb">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://720kb.github.io/csshelper/assets/ext/src/helper.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/angular-datepicker.css">
  <title>Angularjs Datepicker</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="separator50"></div>
  <div class="col6 offset-left2">
    <div class="col3">
      <div class="datepicker"
      date-format="MMMM d, y"
      button-prev='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>'
      button-next='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>'>
      <input ng-model="date2" type="text" class="angular-datepicker-input"/>
    </div>
    Date 2 is: {{date2}}
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/angular-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use ng-repeat to present data from an array. I didn't quite understand what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is  an example of getting JSON Data in Angular Js , can u give us some more information about what the structure of the Json ?

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
    </li>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
     });
     </script>
```

Comment: Sure.Json will contain two values a) date b) price. for every month Structure would be:"Jan": [
      { "day": "2016-10-10", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "day": "2016-10-10", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "day": "2016-10-10", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "day": "2016-10-10", "cost": 2.13 }

Comment: all you'll need is to change x.Name to x.Date
and x.Country to x.Price . that sould do the trick .

Comment: But how would i display the json in the datepicker calendar?How to edit the datepicker calendar.Ex: under date 25 i need to display (Rs.100)

Comment: Well in this case , I would add a function to test wether " {{date2}} " is present in the JSON , if true , get the price for that day by : x.price ( u'll need to loop into the file to find the similar x.date , then u get the price ;)

Comment: Thanku but i need to populate the entire json on display of the calendar.